# SpringBoot and SpringBatch having issues trying to register a Bean e.g. error while injecting

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, spring-boot, spring-batch

My scenario is: there is certain old application which highly depends on `org.w3c.dom.Element` and `org.apache.xerces.dom.DocumentImpl`.

This application reads a spreadsheet from customer, reads many local xml files with parameters, and depending on each node value, it creates a new file. In other words, there are many rules to be applied according to each node value and I must hold them to new application.

My requirement is: I have to create a rest web service which will receive the spreadsheet and process it with same rules. I already decided to use Spring Batch and Spring Boot, even thought it will be my first time with both.

Everything was going right till I tried to inject `org.w3c.dom.Element`.
I carefully read the manual but I must be missing some fundamental concept:

```
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-importing-xml-configuration
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-boot-application.html
```

The error:

```
2015-07-17 05:34:58.405  INFO 15348 --- [           main] hello.BatchConfiguration                 : 
2015-07-17 05:34:58.425  WARN 15348 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'batchController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.batch.core.Job hello.BatchController.job; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'importUserJob' defined in class path resource [hello/BatchConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [org.springframework.batch.core.Step]: : Error creating bean with name 'step1' defined in class path resource [hello/BatchConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 3 of type [org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor]: : Error creating bean with name 'processor': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.w3c.dom.Element hello.MessageItemProcessor.element; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.w3c.dom.Element] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
```

My code:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
public class MessageItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Message, Message> {
       private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageItemProcessor.class);
       @Autowired
       private Element element;
    @Override
    public Message process(final Message message) throws Exception {
       log.info("processing");
       return message;
    }
}
```

application.java

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ImportResource({"classpath*:applicationContext.xml"}) //I just tried it to see what happens
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        Arrays.sort(beanNames);
        for (String beanName : beanNames) {
            System.out.println(beanName); 
        }
    }
}
```

From now on, in fact, there are my tentatives. I am not expecting to be necessary to add `applicationContext.xml`, nor `dispatcher-servelet` neither `web.xml` but I tried to see if it gave me a light.
`applicationContext.xml` because I understood that boot will take care of context initialization. By the way, I tried.

First I just tried to add `applicationContext.xml` in classpath and `@ImportResource`

applicationContext.xml
...

```
       <bean id="element" class="org.w3c.dom.Element" />
</beans>
```

Second I tried use `dispatcher-servlet` been pointed in config.xml
`mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml`
...

```
<bean id="element" class="org.w3c.dom.Element" />
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
       <display-name>test</display-name>
       <servlet>
              <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
              <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
              <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
       </servlet>
       <servlet-mapping>
              <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
              <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
       </servlet-mapping>
       <context-param>
              <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
              <param-value>/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
       </context-param>
       <listener>
              <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
       </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Why on earth are you even trying to inject an Element? That comes from parsing an XML file yu cannot (nor should you)construct it. Seems to me you have your XML skills to level up. Also your web.xml useless in a Spring Boot application so remove it.

Comment: Please, I have been working with Java for the last 10 years but, sometime, I have many difficulties to work with the most suitable techniques. Kindly, give me an idea what would you do? I must not only marshal and unmarshall a object. I must read each node and construct a new file after processed each node separatedly.

Comment: Deinum, I will be very thankfull with any comment. Please, give me an overall idea so I know what I have to search for and a good start point